# Custom plugin add settings option URL after activate plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am implementing a plugin and when activate my plugin then Activate text change to settings and settings link to plugin settings page when activate my plugin.

This is default option when someone installed my plugin

> Active | Delete

When activate my plugin then Active text should be Settings and Settings link to plugin setting page.

> Settings | Deactivate

How can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [plugin_action_links](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugin_action_links/). For example:

```
add_filter( 'plugin_action_links', 'so_plugin_action_links', 10, 2 );

function so_plugin_action_links( $links, $file ) {    

    if ( $file == __FILE__ ) {

        $url = admin_url( 'settings-link.php' );

        $settings_link = '<a href="' . esc_attr( $url ) . '">' . esc_html__( 'Settings' ) . '</a>';

        array_unshift( $links, $settings_link );

    }

    return $links;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,, its help me to sort out this problem. many many thanks

Comment: For some reason this didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
add_filter( 'plugin_action_links_' . plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'my_plugin_action_links' );

function my_plugin_action_links( $links ) {
   $links[] = '<a href="'. esc_url( get_admin_url(null, 'options-general.php?page=settings') ) .'">Settings</a>';  
   return $links;
}
```